# Erro com Laravel sendo usado com API

Tags: laravel

Eu tenho uma aplicação em vuejs que faz requisição pro laravel em localhost, mas quando coloco ambos no servidor (cada um em um servidor) não da pra fazer requisição. Aparece esse erro:

```
net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Procurei em alguns lugares e é algo haver com o CORS

Edit 1:
CORS:

```
'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],//['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'maxAge' => 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa configurar o CORS em seu projeto para gerenciar os acessos a sua aplicação.
Existe uma biblioteca que faz o serviço pesado para você deixando apenas algumas configurações a serem realizadas.

Vou deixar o link da documentação da biblioteca que é muito simples de seguir:
[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: Eu uso esse cors, e está permitindo tudo.
Veja o código no edit 1